# php mssql_connect: failed

Tags: php, mysql, sql-server

I am moving data from a MSSQL database to a MySQL database. I need to connect with PHP to MSSQL and then insert into MySQL. Could someone tell me how to:

- See if the mssql server is running remotely,
- How to connect to it?

Code:

```
mssql_connect($host,$user,$pass) or die('Failed Server Connect! ' . mssql_get_last_message());
mssql_select_db($dbnm) or die('Failed DB Select!');
```

Note: The webserver and db are on separate machines but mysql and mssql are are the same db machine.

I change to:
`$dsnn = "Driver={SQL Server};Server={$host};Database={$dbnm}";`

```
// Connect to the data source and get a handle for that connection.
$conn=odbc_connect($dsnn,$user,$pass);
```

I successfully figured out the Source issue and could not find db issue but now getting:
I now have a message saying: Login failed for user "xxx".

**Figured it out. Was told the wrong password. Reset and now works.**

Comment: What's wrong with the code you posted? Is there an error message?

Comment: Yes, the error for mssql_query seemed sense I am running isapi version of php instead of fastcgi. So I changed to odbc_connect and got it past seeing the server and the db err but now getting user failed.

Comment: Please attempt to format your code.

Comment: What OS is your PHP running on?

Comment: @David, yeah formatting code makes it easier for everyone to read and understand your question. Indent code segments by four spaces and the editor will automatically highlight and format everything for you.

Answer (score 0):

try `**Telnet <IP Address> <Port Number>**` ? Is any error shown?

Comment: What port does MSSQL run on? I know I can access the server because I have MySQL on it running just find cross server.

Comment: It sat there and did nothing on a blank cmd screen

Answer (score 0):

Since you are running PHP on Windows, have you considered trying out the [SqlServer driver for PHP](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?displaylang=en&FamilyID=ccdf728b-1ea0-48a8-a84a-5052214caad9)?  Where I work, we are using it on one of our projects, and have had wonderful results with it.